# isomorphism of étale cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $i: C_0 \hookrightarrow C$ be a nil-immersion (a closed immersion defined by a nilpotent ideal sheaf, so it is a homeomorphism of the underlying topological spaces). Denote by $\mathbb{G}_m$ the multiplicative group, and by $\mathbb{G}_{m,C}$ the sheaf on $C$. (Why) is there an isomorphism of étale cohomology groups $H^i(C_0, i^*\mathbb{G}_{m,C}) \cong H^i(C,\mathbb{G}_{m,C})$?

[Milne, Étale Cohomology], p. 30, Theorem I.3.23 might help, which states that there is an equivalence of étale $C$-schemes and étale $C_0$-schemes.

Comment: More generally this is true for $f:X\to Y$ a finite morphism. This is because $f_\ast$ is exact. You can even compute what $(f_\ast\mathcal{F})_{\overline{y}}$ is explicitly in terms of the geometric points of $X$ lying over $\overline{y}$, and so you can just check the exactness of the stalks (of the pushfowards) directly.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, please? I am a bit confused, since I have $i^*$ and not $i_*$.

Comment: Or did you mean a proof along the following lines: $i_*i^*F = F$ since $j^*F = 0$. Therefore, $H^q(X,F) = H^q(X,i_*i^*F)$, and, $i$ being exact, $H^q(X,i_*i^*F) = H^q(X_0,i^*F)$.